# Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Very simple AJAX request, but it's not working at all. Getting this error i've never seen before:

> Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Contractor/api/plot/LinkBuyer',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        'buyerId': 1,
        'plotId' : parseInt(sPlotId, 10),
        'activateDirectly': true
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please add the error stack trace to the question also.

Comment: So, where are you trying to access `mode`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: @Cerbrus Perhaps some jquery internal? But we can only know for sure if the stack trace is available.

Comment: It references this: "Function.t.ajaxPrefilter.t.ajax"

Comment: at Function.t.ajaxPrefilter.t.ajax (jquery.validate.js:1588)

Answer (score 39):

Got the answer! I was using the slim version of jquery...

Comment: nice tip! Thank you

Comment: Yes. I faced similar issue because I was using the slim jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem using jquery ui to show an hidden element.

```
jQuery('#myId').show({effect: 'Blind', duration: 800});
```

The problem is that the effect name is in lowercase, so the right line of javascript is

```
jQuery('#myId').show({effect: 'blind', duration: 800});
```